# iOS How to call func from another View Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have one problem, i want call one method from **firstVC** to **seccondVC** i try to use such code:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "MainScreenVC", bundle: nil)
let firstViewController: MainScreenVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainScreenVC") as! MainScreenVC
firstViewController.automatingFullFill()
```

But immediately i received error, what is wrong?

My error:

> 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainScreenVC' in bundle NSBundle

Comment: what this function do ? and MainScreenVC is already initiated or this is first time initialisation ?

Comment: You are giving Storyboard name and viewcontroller as same,make  sure that  Storyboard name and ViewController name is same .

Comment: It's sure same name

Comment: If you didn't change your storyboard name then it will be 'Main' not `MainScreenVC`. so use `let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)`

Comment: Yes, now it's working, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are taking seperate storyboard for every viewcontroller you have to give storyboard name and viewcontroller name .

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "give storyboard name here ", bundle: nil)
let firstViewController: MainScreenVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontrollername here") as! MainScreenVC
firstViewController.automatingFullFill()
```

(OR)
You can call it like this also

```
 let mainScreenVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "give Storyboard name here", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller") as! MainScreenVC
```